# Is it bad for SEO to have an 'article' published under 2 urls?

Tags: seo

On our new website we publish an article once and can tag it to appear in several sections eg.

blahblah.com/insight/10-05-21/Buzzcity-releases-mobile-game-library.aspx

blahblah.com/international_media/10-05-21/Buzzcity-releases-mobile-game-library.aspx

Is it better for SEO to have the 2 different urls which include important keywords like ‘insight’ and ‘international media’ or is it better to have a single generic url?  E.g.
blahblah.com/articles/10-05-21/Buzzcity_releases_mobile_game_library.aspx

I read somewhere that google doesn’t like the same content ‘duplicated’ in 2 (or 3) places - I am not a tecchie.

THanks

Comment: This is not a question about programming, and therefore doesn't belong here.  It looks like a serious sysadmin question to me, and therefore belongs on Server Fault.

Comment: The design of website URLs is often left to programmers, especially on small and individual projects.

Comment: Double correction - there's a third forum for this, apparently; http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Google will penalise for duplication. The way that you should solve this is to indicate a canonical url scheme to Google.

See: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359 and http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139066

Personally, I would put all the keywords you want in one heading and always remember the golden rule of SEO: the best way to get good rankings is to have good, relevant, content.

Answer (score 0):

A canonical link should *only* be used if the duplicate content problem cannot be solved at it's source. Assuming you're in charge of the URL-scheme of the website, you should consider reformatting it.

Personally, I try to keep a hierarchical url-scheme. If your articles are related to a number of things (tags, authors, sections), think about how your data is related. If your article *cannot logically exist* without a related element (e.g. deleting a section from a newspaper, would logically cause a cascade delete on it's articles) it should be considered for use as parent in the URL hierarchy. If no such relation is present, the URL-scheme should be formatted accordingly.

Consider the following examples. You can choose between a number of parents for your articles `example.com/authors/alichard/articles/buzzcity...`,
`example.com/tags/insight/articles/buzzcity...`, etc.

In the end, there is no *right* way to do it. But IMHO you should either stash all your tags in the article URL (`example.com/insight+international_media/buzzcity...`) or go for a tag-less article URL (`example.com/articles/buzzcity` and `example.com/articles/tagged/insight` for article listing).

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I'm not sure if i've misled you slightly by reference to tags/keywords...  the out-of-the-box CMS solution creates the url including the website section name (e.g insight or international media - it's an online marketing magazine) - so they are hierarchical urls i think.

I'm the client but I'm trying to guide my web design company who have very little SEO experience.